# How to undersample a unbalanced multiclass Dataset? (Python)

Tags: python, dataset, sklearn-pandas, multiclass-classification

I have a unbalanced dataset with 5 classes. Now i want so undersample it to make it more balanced. But i can´t find a code for this, just for binary class problems.

Do someone have a sample code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scikit-learn balanced subsampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455728/scikit-learn-balanced-subsampling)

Comment: If you want to be helped more efficiently, you should be more specific by showing a extract of your data, the needed results and the code you have so far or at least a reference to the code you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use SMOTE for that. Here is how you undersample: 
https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/under_sampling.html